# Mount settings_local.py file to container in Azure CI

Tags: azure, docker, azure-container-instances

I'm trying out azure CI (aci) but ran directly into problems:

I try to get a bitpoll docker image chessmasterrr/bitpoll running in Azure CI and I'm struggling how to mount the settings file.

The manual in docker hub says to mount the file as /path/on/host/settings_local.py:/Bitpoll/bitpoll/settings_local.py.

Has anybody an idea how to get that running in azure?

I tried to put it in a azure file share or mount it as a base64 encoded secret.

Answer (score 0):

The following configuration helped me deploy the ACI with the docker image. However, issues remain with container termination loop though...

To deploy the ACI container 'succesfully':

1. Create a Storage account with two file shares:
   [image]
   The names are arbitrary and can be anything.
   What is important is that one of them will hold the 'settings.py' file and the other the database content.

   [image]

In one of the fileshares put the 'settings.py' file. The [Docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/r/chessmasterrr/bitpoll) mentions a 'settings_local.py' file but that does not work afaik as this output shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 387, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues = run_checks(tags=[Tags.database])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/checks/database.py", line 9, in check_database_backends
    for conn in connections.all():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 216, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitpoll.settings'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Bitpoll/./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 336, in run_from_argv
    connections.close_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 219, in close_all
    for alias in self:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 213, in __iter__
    return iter(self.databases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 147, in databases
    self._databases = settings.DATABASES
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 984, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bitpoll.settings'
```

2. And then the ARM template:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "containerGroupName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the Azure Container Instance group"
            },
            "defaultValue": "demo_container_group_unique"
        },
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Location of the reosurces to be deployed"
            },
            "defaultValue": "westeurope"
        },
        "storageAccountName": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "Name of the storage account"
            },
            "defaultValue": "storage_account_unique"
        },
        "storageAccountKeyValue": {
            "type": "string",
            "metadata": {
                "description": "The storage account key (value)"
            }
        }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2021-10-01",
            "name": "[parameters('containerGroupName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "sku": "Standard",
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "name": "publiccmbp3",
                        "properties": {
                            "command": ["./manage.py", "migrate"],
                            "image": "chessmasterrr/bitpoll",
                            "ports": [
                                {
                                    "port": 8000
                                }
                            ],
                            "environmentVariables": [
                            ],
                            "resources": {
                                "requests": {
                                    "memoryInGB": 4,
                                    "cpu": 2
                                }
                            },
                            "volumeMounts": [
                                {
                                    "name": "onlyfile",
                                    "mountPath": "/Bitpoll/bitpoll/",
                                    "readOnly": false
                                },
                                {
                                    "name": "database",
                                    "mountPath": "/Bitpoll/database/",
                                    "readOnly": false
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }

                ],
                "restartPolicy": "Never",
                "ipAddress": {
                    "ports": [
                        {
                            "port": 8000
                        }
                    ],
                    "ip": "10.0.2.4",
                    "type": "Public"
                },
                "osType": "Linux",
                "volumes": [
                    {
                        "name": "onlyfile",
                        "azureFile": {
                            "shareName": "onlyfile",
                            "readOnly": false,
                            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
                            "storageAccountKey": "[parameters( 'storageAccountKeyValue')]"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "database",
                        "azureFile": {
                            "shareName": "database",
                            "readOnly": false,
                            "storageAccountName": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
                            "storageAccountKey": "[parameters( 'storageAccountKeyValue')]"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

This template deploys the ACI with the image. It also executes the initial command that is mentioned on docker hub:

```
"command": ["./manage.py", "migrate"]
```

3. Next will be the deployment of the ARM template.
   I wrote a small powershell script that assists with deployment:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

$RESOURCEGROUPNAME  = "az204demo"
$STORAGEACCOUNTNAME = "az204ferdi"
$NEWRESOURCEGROUP   = "testres110"
$ARMTEMPLATE        = "TemplateACiExample.json"
$ACINAME            = "myacitest11"
Connect-AzAccount

$STORAGEACCOUNT     = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCEGROUPNAME -Name $STORAGEACCOUNTNAME
$STORAGERESOURCEID  = $STORAGEACCOUNT.ResourceId
$STORAGEACCOUNTKEYS = Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $RESOURCEGROUPNAME -Name $STORAGEACCOUNTNAME

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $NEWRESOURCEGROUP -Location "WestEurope" 
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment   -ResourceGroupName $NEWRESOURCEGROUP  `
                                -containerGroupName $ACINAME `
                                -storageAccountName $STORAGEACCOUNTNAME `
                                -storageAccountKeyValue $STORAGEACCOUNTKEYS[0].Value `
                                -TemplateFile $ARMTEMPLATE
```

After deployment a new sqlite file is created in the database fileshare:
[image]

Unfortunately the ACI enters into an endless loop/termination afterwards. The log service provided with the ACI also does not offer any information.
Hopefully this answers your question regarding the volumes and helps you to succesfully use the docker image.

Kind regards